# SSAS ErrorCode="3239575554" Either the user does not have permissions to alter the 'SERVER' object

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, security, ssas

I have just installed SSAS on a server called SASBIO1, 
but when I try to run the script below, in order to grant Administrator rights to a specific AD group I get the error message:

```
<Error ErrorCode="3239575554" Description="Either the 'mycompany\MMiorelli' user does not have permission to alter the 'SASBI01' object, or the object does not exist." Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Analysis Services" HelpFile="" />
```

This script grants Admin to BIUsersLIVE:

```
<Batch xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine' Transaction='true'>
    <Alter AllowCreate="true" ObjectExpansion="ObjectProperties" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
        <Object />
        <ObjectDefinition>
            <Server xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400">
                <ID>SASBI01</ID>
                <Name>SASBI01</Name>
            </Server>
        </ObjectDefinition>
    </Alter>
    <Alter AllowCreate="true" ObjectExpansion="ObjectProperties" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
        <Object>
            <RoleID>Administrators</RoleID>
        </Object>
        <ObjectDefinition>
            <Role xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400">
                <ID>Administrators</ID>
                <Name>Administrators</Name>
                <Members>
                    <Member>
                        <Name>mycompany\BIUserslive</Name>
                    </Member>
                </Members>
            </Role>
        </ObjectDefinition>
    </Alter>
</Batch>
```

The same error happens when I try to do it from SSMS, as you can see on the picture below.
[image]

I know I am admin, I am the DBA who installed it.

What is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this was really nonsense.
I right click on ssms and run as administrator, and added the permission there without a problem.

[image]